# Custom Source presence checking method name in MapStruct

Tags: option-type, mapstruct

is it posible to generate a custom "presence checking" method name, being a method of the property itself rather the owning object?

I know I can use *hasProperty()* methods to check for presence of a value...
https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#source-presence-check

but with Optional or JsonNullable (from OpenApi nonullable) that checking method is on the property itself, not on the owning object... :-(

I can map JsonNullable or Optional easyly 'using' or extending a simple custom Mapper

```
@Mapper
public class JsonNullableMapper {

    public <T> T fromJsonNullable(final JsonNullable<T> jsonNullable) {
        return jsonNullable.orElse(null);
    }

    public <T> JsonNullable<T> asJsonNullable(final T nullable) {
        return nullable != null ? JsonNullable.of(nullable) : JsonNullable.undefined();
    }

}
```

what I would like to achieve is something like this as "presence check":

```
if(source.getProperty().isPresent()) {
    target.set(customMapper.map(source.getProperty()));
}
```

Any one found a solution for this?

Thanks and regards

Comment: It is currently not possible in MapStruct to do this directly. Your alternative `JsonNullableMapper`  seems a rather nice solution to me. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I would like to get the presence checker in adition to this mapper... I want only to set target property if source is present

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to implement custom [lombok extension](https://github.com/kokorin/lombok-presence-checker/) which generates "presence checknig" methods.

Here is an [example project](https://github.com/kokorin/lombok-presence-checker/tree/main/lombok-presence-checker-example). In short I added `@PresenceChecker` annotation and implemented Lombok Javac Annotation handler.

It's possible to use it together with other Lombok annotations:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    private String name;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@PresenceChecker
public class UserUpdateDto {
    private String name;
}

//MapStruct Mapper interface declaration
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {
    void updateUser(UserUpdateDto dto, @MappingTarget User user);
}
```

Generated code:

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class UserUpdateDto {
    private boolean hasName;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hasName = true;
    }

    public boolean hasName() {
        return this.hasName;
    }
}

//MapStruct Mapper implementation
public class UserMapperImpl implements UserMapper {
    @Override
    public void updateUser(UserUpdateDto dto, User user) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( dto.hasName() ) {
            user.setName( dto.getName() );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is unfortunately a straight no.

It is not possible in the current version of MapStruct (1.3.1final) and its not on the shortlist for 1.4.0. You could open up an issue on the git repo of MapStruct as feature request.