# Generate MapStruct presence checker methods with Lombok

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

MapStruct is aware of [source presence checking](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#source-presence-check)
and uses presence checker methods by default (if present of course) to verify if a field in a target object should be updated with a value in a source
object. Without presence checkers MapStruct by default updates only fields with non-null values.

I want to use DTO in a REST controller to implement partial update strategy using MapStruct's source presence checknig but since I use Lombok to generate getters and setters I also want to generate source presence checking methods.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to do that. SOURCE: Me. I'm a core lombok contributor.

However, there is a recent, and very long, feature request discussion on this very idea: [Issue #2669: Generate hasXXX() method](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2669). It goes in multiple wrong directions, so I would suggest you start from the end, where some concrete plans on how to get there from here are listed. It's complicated.

Comment: There is a way to do it via lombok extension and it works: https://github.com/kokorin/lombok-presence-checker. I wanted to answer my own question, but the answer was deleted by a moderator.

Answer (score 0):

In short I created a lombok extension which supports `@PresenceChecker` annotation and generates `hasXXX()` methods.

```
// Original code
@PresenceChecker
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserUpdateDto {
    private String name;
}

//Generated code
public class UserUpdateDto {
    private boolean hasName;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hasName = true;
    }

    public boolean hasName() {
        return this.hasName;
    }
}
```

More detailed answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65466220/4912398)